Identify a 70's TV show...
Back in the 70's there was a short lived adenveture series, in which Earth was almost destroyed after a nuclear disaster... 3 people (1 elderly, a young man and a young woman, and a monkey) rode along the USA with a BOX on wheels... they wore (I think) Red & White uniform, and used a mirror and sun-beams as weapons... does it ring a bel?!

Was this animated or live action?

Country of origin?

Was the "monkey" actually a chimpanzee?  Was the "BOX" actually a "a futuristic-looking six-wheeled combination RV and mobile laboratory"?  If so, then you're probably thinking of Ark II, (1976).

For millions of years, Earth was fertile and rich. Then pollution and
  waste began to take their toll. Civilization fell into ruin. This is
  the world of the 25th century. Only a handful of scientists remain,
  men who have vowed to rebuild what has been destroyed. This is their
  achievement: Ark II, a mobile storehouse of scientific knowledge,
  manned by a highly trained crew of young people. Their mission: to
  bring the hope of a new future to mankind.




Thanks!!!!!!! That is INDEED what I was looking for! It was aired in Israel in the mid-80's during the summer holiday in the mornings... for a while, buying pocket mirrors in Israel was a hit
